# Exception when swapping value from one listbox to another listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, datasource

I have two listboxes. When I swap values from one listbox to another I get an exception `Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.` How can i resolve it?

Below the code where I bind my listbox and swap values

For swapping values I use this :

```
 private void MoveListBoxItems(ListBox lstEmployeelist, ListBox lstSelectedEmployees)
    {

        ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection sourceItems = lstEmployeelist.SelectedItems;


        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= sourceItems.Count - 1; i++ )
            {
                object item = sourceItems[i];

                lstSelectedEmployees.Items.Add(item);
                lstEmployeelist.Items.RemoveAt(i);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

And for binding Listbox I use this code

```
if (_empComponent == null)
            _empComponent = new EmployeeComponent();
        lstEmployeelist.DataSource = _empComponent.GetEmpCodeWithName();
        lstEmployeelist.ValueMember = "Empno";
        lstEmployeelist.DisplayMember = "FirstName";
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy: When you use a `DataSource` you cannot modify the `Items` collection since the items are being filled automatically from the data source.

Change the data source instead, which would be the data structure behind `_empComponent.GetEmpCodeWithName()`

Comment: First time when load the page i fill the All Employees form the function without this how can lisbox have some values

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in the DataSource list instead - save it in sime provate field before assignment,

```
if (_empComponent == null)
    _empComponent = new EmployeeComponent();

_myPrivateCollection = _empComponent.GetEmpCodeWithName();
lstEmployeelist.DataSource = _myPrivateCollection;
lstEmployeelist.ValueMember = "Empno";
lstEmployeelist.DisplayMember = "FirstName";
```

When needed, change and then reassign the DataSource:

```
//I don't know your logic here, but probably there is a bug - you are modifying collection and then use old index position - you'll get unexpected results =). Let you fix it on your own, so just rewrite your code
for (int i = 0; i <= lstEmployeelist.SelectedIndices.Count; i++ )
{
    var index = lstEmployeelist.SelectedIndices[i]
    object item = _myPrivateCollection[index];

    _myPrivateCollection.Add(item);
    _myPrivateCollection.RemoveAt(index);
}
lstEmployeelist.DataSource = null;
lstEmployeelist.DataSource = _myPrivateCollection;
```

Please note that this technique shouldn't be used often with very big lists as it is slow operation. But it's the simplest way to accomplish your needs.

Comment: edited my answer - added more code. Please give attention to comment about logical bug in your code

Comment: @Olesandr Pshenychnyy Thanks for your reply I am using bindingsource on my page this work fine but how can i assign these value that have change to binding source

Comment: BindingSource itself has DataSource property. Use it in the same way like I described

Comment: ok i am faceing problem that is when `_myPrivateCollection.Add(item);`
    `_myPrivateCollection.RemoveAt(index);` here i get the current value but the listbox not display the current value i also Listbox1.refresh() but not any effect on the listbox